# argmax for multidimensional array along some axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a multidimension array that looks like this:

```
my_array = np.arange(2)[:,None,None] *np.arange(4)[:, None]*np.arange(8)
```

I am looking for a multidimensional equivalent of the 2-D [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

In particular, I am looking for argmax of maxima along axis = 2. I tried reshaping first, but reshaping will completely destroy the original indices information of the entire array, so it probably won't work. I have no clue how to do it and need helps from you guys. Thank you in advance

EDIT: Desire output is:

```
[(0,0,0),(1,3,1),(1,3,2),(1,3,3),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,3,7)]
```

This exactly is the array of the indices of maxima along axis = 2

Comment: So, `my_array.argmax(axis=2)`?

Comment: thanks for your help @Divakar. my_array.argmax(axis=2) does generate an array, but it is not the indices of the maxima along the axis = 2. I will edit the post to clarity what the desired output is

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding such argmax indices along the last axis of a 3D ndarray, we can use something along these lines -

```
In [66]: idx = my_array.reshape(-1,my_array.shape[-1]).argmax(0)

In [67]: r,c = np.unravel_index(idx,my_array.shape[:-1])

In [68]: l = np.arange(len(idx))

In [69]: np.c_[r,c,l]
Out[69]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 6],
       [1, 3, 7]])
```

To extend this to a generic ndarray -

```
In [99]: R = np.unravel_index(idx,my_array.shape[:-1])

In [104]: np.hstack((np.c_[R],l[:,None]))
Out[104]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 6],
       [1, 3, 7]])
```

Comment: Thank you @Divakar. I could never come up with this.